# How to use HashRouter and anchor navigation on the page together in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using `HashRouter` from `react-router-dom` and when I am trying to use an anchor tag:

`<a href="#div-id"> Link to div </a>`

which links it to a div on the same page with an id `div-id`, it redirects the user to default Route as the the url `.../#/div-id` is not mentioned in any of the paths of `Route`.

How do I achieve directing user to a div with `id = "div-id"` in the same page I am using anchor tag, while using HashRouter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HashLink from react-router-hash-link;

`npm i react-router-hash-link --force`

`<HashLink to="/#div-id"> Link to div</HashLink>`